# saving emails as pdf files

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Our client have a workflow that sends out emails, pretty standard stuff.

Now the client wants to save these emails, or the content of it, as pdf files to some list.

Can it be done and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint does not provide native support for converting Email to PDF. You will need to write (very) extensive code in order to make this work. There aren't even any (horrible) shortcuts where you can let Outlook do the work via COM automation.

You will need to have a look at 3rd party software. A quick Google search will return a number of software libraries that can be used to extract content from emails, which you can then turn into a PDF using yet another set of 3rd party PDF generation software.

There is also an easy answer, which is to buy a copy of the PDF Converter for SharePoint, which comes with various workflow activities (SharePoint Designer, Nintex Workflow, Visual Studio Workflows as well as an API) and comes with [very extensive support for EML and MSG files](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2013/11/convert-msg-and-eml-based-emails-to-pdf.html) (including attachments).

Please note that I worked on this product so consider me biased (yet an expert on the topic of converting email to PDF)